# What is the type of (1 2) in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, hugs

I was playing around with hugs today and got stuck at a very simple question:

```
λ 1 1
:: (Num a, Num (a -> t)) => t
```

What would that type be? I am having trouble to read this.

And if it has a type, why? I would guess that the expression `1 1` is ill-formed and thus type-checking fails, which is supported by the Haskell compiler.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No it is not ill-formed. The type is strange and there probably cannot be any meaningful values for which it makes sense but it's still allowed.

Keep in mind that literals are overloaded. `1` is **not** an integer. It's anything of type `Num`.  Functions are *not* excluded from this. There is no rule saying `a -> t` *cannot* be " a number" (i.e. an instance of `Num`).

For example you could have an `instance` declaration like:

```
instance Num a => Num (a -> b) where
    fromInteger x = undefined
    [...]
```

now `1 1` would simply be equal `undefined`. Not very useful but still valid.

You *can* have useful definitions of `Num` for functions. For example, from the [wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Num_instance_for_functions)

```
instance Num b => Num (a -> b) where
     negate      = fmap negate
      (+)         = liftA2 (+)
      (*)         = liftA2 (*)
      fromInteger = pure . fromInteger
      abs         = fmap abs
      signum      = fmap signum
```

With this you can write things like:

```
f + g
```

where `f` and `g` are functions returning numbers.

Using the above instance declaration `1 2` would be equal to `1`.
Basically a literal used as a function with the above instance is equal to `const <that-literal>`.

Comment: By the way, are there any practical examples of an expression such as `1 2` or `True "hello"` or `"hello" [1,2,3]` etc being useful? DSLs I guess?

Comment: `True` is not overloaded – it is an actual constructor of the `data Bool = False | True` data type

Comment: @ErikAllik I have never seen this used in this way. It may be possible but AFAIK isn't used.

Comment: Small but important nitpick of "It's anything of type `Num`.": `Num` is not a type. `Num` is a *typeclass*.

Answer (score 5):

In Haskell, `1` doesn't have a fixed type. It is "any numeric type". More exactly, any type that implements the `Num` class.

In particular, it is technically valid for a *function type* to be an instance of `Num`. Nobody would ever do that, but technically it's possible.

So the compiler is assuming that the *first* `1` is some sort of numeric function type, and then the *second* `1` is any other number type (maybe the same type, maybe a different one). If we change the expression to, say, `3 6`, then the compiler is assuming

```
3 :: Num (x -> y) => x -> y
6 :: Num x => x
3 6 :: (Num (x -> y), Num x) => y
```

Comment: Well it causes a bit of a mess when you make functions an instance of `Num`, but I wouldn't say nobody would ever do that. It is useful in the same sense that a `Monoid` instance of functions is useful: you can for example write something like `(+5) * (+3)` and get a new function that does `\x -> (x + 5) * (x + 3)`, I think that is pretty cool. See also [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Num_instance_for_functions).